# (Tao's Ex 1.1.3) Uniqueness of elementary measures; confused how to proceed.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is an exercise from Tao's Introduction to Measure Theory.

> Exercise 1.1.3:($\textit{uniqueness of elementary measure}$) Let $d \ge 1$. Let $m':\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^d)\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ be a map from the collection $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ of elementary subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ to the non negative reals that obeys the non-negativity, finite additivity and translation invariance. Show that there exists a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that $m'(E)=c\,m(E)$ for all elementary sets $E$. In prticular, if we impose the additional normalisation $m'\left([0,1)^d\right)=1$ then $m' \equiv m$.

**Attempt:** Given hint: set $c:=m'([0,1]^d)$ and then compute $m'\left([0,\tfrac{1}{n})^d\right)$. For simplicity I've tried for $d=1$. Partitioning we get $E:=[0,1)=[0,\tfrac{1}{n})\cup [\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac{2}{n})\cup \cdots \cup [\tfrac{n-1}{n},1)$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now translating $[0,1)$ by $\tfrac{k}{n}$ we get $[\tfrac{k}{n},\tfrac{k+1}{n})$ where $k=1,\ldots,n-1$. Now given that $m'$ obeys translation invariance, then we write  $$m'\left([0,\tfrac{1}{n})\right)=m'\left([\tfrac{k}{n},\tfrac{k+1}{n})\right)$$ Now using the finite additivity property we get
\begin{align}
    m'([0,1))&=m' \left(\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1}[\tfrac{k}{n},\tfrac{k+1}{n})\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}m' \left([\tfrac{k}{n},\tfrac{k+1}{n})\right)\nonumber \\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}m'([0,\tfrac{1}{n})]=n\cdot m'([0,\tfrac{1}{n}))\nonumber
\end{align}
This gives us $m'([0,\tfrac{1}{n}))=\tfrac{1}{n}m'([0,1))=c\cdot m([0,\tfrac{1}{n})).$
I can do this for any $d$, also setting $m'([0,1)^d)=1$, i will have $m'\equiv m.$ But does intervals of type $[0,\tfrac{1}{n})$ exhaust all possibilities? Don't i need to consider also intervals of the form $[0,a)^d$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$? I'm confused at this stage. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $c=m'(Q_1)$ where $Q_1$ is the standard $1$-box. Note that $m(Q_1)=1$. Now divide $Q_1$ into $2^{nd}\ \ 2^{-n}$boxes which are necessarily disjoint. It follows that if $Q$ is a $2^{-n}$-box, then $2^{nd}m'(Q)=m'(Q_1)=cm(Q_1)=c2^{nd}m(Q)\Rightarrow m'(Q)=cm(Q).$ So the result holds for any $2^{-n}$-box.

In fact, we get even more from this: since every open set is a countable disjoint union of such sets, the result is true for any open set and so for any Borel set by regularity of the measures $m$ and $m'$.

Comment: Thanks! You're doing this for $d$ dimensional case, with box of the type $[0,\tfrac{1}{n})^d$ right? But by doubt was, how to do it for intervals of type $[0,a)^d$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. The case when $[0,\tfrac{p}{q})^d$ is done, i guess i need to use the fact the $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ to arrive at a conclusion.

Comment: My answer (taken from Papa Rudin) shows that the result is true for all Borel sets so in particular, for $[0,a)^d.$ From scratch you can write $[0,a)^d$  as an increasing union of boxes and then use continuity of the measures.

Comment: Ah okay! I've just started measure theory, I don't know about Borel sets yet. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Well, you can do it from scratch: We have the result $m'([k/n,(k+1)/n))=cm([k/n,(k+1)/n))$ for any integers $k,m$. Without loss of generality $0<a<1$ so that $k<n$. We want to show that $m'([0,a))=cm'([0,a)).$ Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $k,n$ such that $m([0,a))<m([0,k/n))+\epsilon$ and similarly for $m'$. Then $|cm([0,a))-m'([0,a))|<|cm([0,a))-cm([0,k/n))|+|cm([0,k/n))-m'([0,k/n))|+|m'([0,k/n))-m'([0,a)))|<(c+1)\epsilon.$

Comment: Nice, this works fine.